# Spring JMS ActiveMQ track status of jobs

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

In my `Spring` web service there are some asynchronous processes. Client request with some parameters I create a `Job` object from those parameters and put into a `ActiveMQ` queue using `JMS`. So a listener will take those jobs from the queue and process them. Now I need to provide clients a way to track the status of their jobs (`pending, started, finished`). What is the best way to implement this?

I thought I can use `JMSTemplate.browse()` with a `BrowserCallBack` but still could not find a way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to have a DB to track the job status.

The client just ask the statistics and you `select` it from DB.

You can use another JMS `queue` to send the status of job to perstist in onto DB using appropriate listener.

And with that you will have a good `loosely-coupling`: your first listener won't have a direct connection to the DB service.